# remove consecutive lines urls in notepad++

Tags: notepad++

```
subject1
image url follows here
[img]http:f6.abc.com/246421f...
[img]http:f6.abc.com/246421d...
[img]http:f6.abc.com/246421h...
[img]http:f6.abc.com/246421m...
download url follows here
[url]link1[/url]

subject2
image url follows here
[img]http:z.uvw.com/7862252...
[img]http:z.uvw.com/4621017...
[img]http:z.uvw.com/4728212...
[img]http:z.uvw.com/78293.5...
download url follows here
[url]link2[/url]
```

similarly, I have tons of blocks. I need only one image url(file has many images urls immediately after it), first image url is best. That means, i need the output as below

```
subject1
image url follows here
[img]http:f6.abc.com/246421f...
download url follows here
[url]link1[/url]

subject2
image url follows here
[img]http:z.uvw.com/7862252...
download url follows here
[url]link2[/url]
```

Comment: Please [edit] the question and give **real** examples of the before and after data.

Answer (score 0):

In notepad++ find replace dialog:

- look for:
  `(\[img\].+\n)(\[img\].+\n)*`
- replace to:
  `$1`
- check "regular expression"
- click "replace all"

you can test it [here](https://regex101.com/r/ABRH6X/1)

Comment: Actually, its not working with my real links. Here is https://regex101.com/r/P4UqIx/1 
the file is separated with *s. I need only one image, but its not working in my situation. 
Thank you for your quick response. Waiting for another response from you.

Comment: I would liked not to know which links you use:(... please update your question to show the real structure of your case and I'll update my answer after. Currently the structure in your question (only `[img]`) is different from the one in your case (`[img]` and `[link]`) mixed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to go:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^(\[img\].+\R)(?1)*`
- Replace with: `$1`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           : begining of line
(           : start group 1
  \[img\]   : literally [img]
  .+        : 1 or more any character but newline
  \R        : any kind of linebreak (\r, \n, \r\n)
)           : end group 1
(?1)*       : same pattern that the one is defined in group 1, 0 or more times
```

*DO NOT CHECK `. matches newline`*

**Replacement:**

```
$1          : content of group 1
```

**Result for given example:**

```
subject1
image url follows here
[img]http:f6.abc.com/246421f...
download url follows here
[url]link1[/url]

subject2
image url follows here
[img]http:z.uvw.com/7862252...
download url follows here
[url]link2[/url]
```